# kdb - sending large CSV from local to server

Tags: kdb

All,
I'm having some trouble sending a large csv-based tables (6 cols x 1mm+ rows) table to my server. I can bring tables back from my server with no issues. I've tried a few methods but presently I'm trying to read the csv and send it over as a string to build the table on the server. Perhaps I'm overlooking something very simple when assigning variables in the server string?

In trying to find a solution, I have been testing .Q.fs as it reads rows and inserts to a table thinking that I could just send a string and rebuild the table on the server. https://code.kx.com/q/kb/loading-from-large-files/#using-qfs

```
tbl: ("SIISSS";enlist",") 0:`:/data/local.csv; //how I normally load tables locally
```

Since I am unable to sort out how to send a tbl directly to the server, I was thinking of reading and  sending as a string

```
//build table locally and insert records
 tbl:([]AAA:`first_row;BBB:1?10;CCC:2;DDD:`first_row;EEE:`first_row;FFF:`first_row); //create table tbl;
.Q.fs[{`tbl insert flip (cols tbl)!("SIISSS";",")0:x}]`:./Data/local.csv;   //load locally saved data;
tbl: delete from tbl where AAA =`first_row; //clean up by removing dummy data;
```

However, I'm not able to transfer this data to my server. I assume its my syntax assigning variables. I thought I would just read a file as text to send over and then save as a local csv on the server though  I prefer not to save files there.

```
//try to send csv data from local to server
\p 5042;
h:hopen `:xxx.xxx.xx.xx:5042;
h "tbl:([]AAA:`first_row;BBB:1?10;CCC:2;DDD:`first_row;EEE:`first_row;FFF:`first_row)";  //create table on server

//TRYING TO READ TABLE AND SEND DATA TO SERVER 
csv_string: raze read0[./Data/local.csv];  //<--- read the file in as a razed string
h "data:" , csv_string ;  //                 <-----no luck assigning variable
h "save `/data/csv_string.csv";//            <-----save file to server directory to reference later
```

If I can get the file saved as a csv on the server then at lease I can just reference it.

```
h ".Q.fs[{`tbl insert flip (cols tbl)!("SIISSS";",")0:x}]`:/data/csv_string.csv";  //
h "tbl: delete from tbl where AAA =`first_row"; //clean up by removing dummy data;
hclose h
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can hold the entire csv/table in memory client side. You could use the  `h(func;args)` notation for ipc. Edit - corrected link: https://code.kx.com/q/learn/startingkdb/ipc/

Either use assign apply in the root namespace:

```
h({@[`.;`tbl;:;x]};([]a:1 2 3;b:`a`b`c))
```

or global assign:

```
h({tbl::x};localTblVariable)
```

Comment: Thanks Matt....looks like my issue then is taking it from a csv and putting into the ([ ] a: ...) format for 1mm records. I can store the table in memory fortunately, its just taking it from csv and transforming to fit the argument. Ill keep looking tonight!

Comment: Sorry I should of made it more clear, you don't have to do any fancy formatting. Just load the csv to a variable locally and send that to the server peocess. e.g. `localTblVariable`

Comment: Thanks Matt, this works cleanly.  At present I'm not using global variables so I went with the `h (funs;args)` notation and it worked immediately. I've read and am still referencing Q for Mortals and including ipc but had no luck locating this on the kx site. [link] (https://code.kx.com/q/basics/ipc/). I've successfully pushed other functions, q files to my server but simply sending a table has been a problem.  This helps a lot!

Comment: I've also been referencing here looking here: [link] (https://code.kx.com/q4m3/11_IO/#116-interprocess-communication) . It looks like their example  `h (sq; 5)` has the similar notation.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Matt's suggestion is the best way to go when assigning variables on the server side.

With this, you can define variables from the local process (IE the table/csv in this case) in the server process.

```
// local process
q)h:hopen 23444
q)show local:("SIISSS";enlist",")0:`:local.csv
AAA       BBB CCC DDD       EEE       FFF
-----------------------------------------------
first_row 8   2   first_row first_row first_row
q)h({@[`.;`data;:;x]};local)
`.

// server process
q)\p
23444i
q)data
AAA       BBB CCC DDD       EEE       FFF
-----------------------------------------------
first_row 8   2   first_row first_row first_row
q)save`:data.csv
`:data.csv
q)("SIISSS";enlist",")0:`:data.csv
AAA       BBB CCC DDD       EEE       FFF
-----------------------------------------------
first_row 8   2   first_row first_row first_row
```

Comment: Thanks once again Cathal. I tested this morning and it worked like a charm.  Seems this would be a good thing to incorporate into Q for Mortals. I have had no issues sending many other items (functions, scripts, queries, etc.) but this has eluded me and its embarrassingly simply now that both you and Matt have illustrated how to do it.  Many thanks again.